# Why does '+' + a short convert to 44

Tags: c#

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
MyObject.PhoneNumber = '+' + ThePhonePrefix + TheBizNumber;
```

Basically, I'm creating a phone number in E164 format and then I assign that string to a string property of an object. ThePhonePrefix is a short that holds the international phone prefix and TheBizNumber is a string that holds the phone number digits.

Why didn't the compiler bug when I was concatenating a short in the string in the first place? And then why does '+' + 1 equal 44?? This was a pretty hard bug to track because there was no compile error and 44 is the phone prefix for the UK so everything "looked" like it was working because the client-side code just saw a UK number. Why 44?

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks everybody; we learn everyday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why didn't the compiler bug when I was concatenating a short in the
>   string in the first place?

String concatenation using `+` sign internally calls `string.Concat`, which internally calls `ToString` on each parameter. Hence no error.

> why does '+' + 1

You are doing character/numeric arithmetic. `43` being value of `+` and short/int `1` is 44.

**Because of operator + associativity from left to right it is first character/numeric addition and then string concatenation.**

So it is like:

```
MyObject.PhoneNumber = ('+' + ThePhonePrefix) + TheBizNumber;
```

You can use `"+"` to mark it as a string or explicitly call `String.Concat` like:

```
var result = string.Concat('+', ThePhonePrefix, TheBizNumber);
```

Answer (score 8):

43 is the (http://www.asciitable.com/) ascii value of the character '+'. The compiler interprets `char` addition as, well, addition, rather than concatenation. Try `"+"` instead to get the expected string behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`'+'` is the `+` character.

`"+"` is the `+` string.

When using the `+` operator to add/concatenate, the `+` character (`'+'`) will convert to an integer.

When using the `+` operator to add/concatenate, the `+` string (`"+"`) will convert the other operands to a string.

What you wrote equates to:

```
MyObject.PhoneNumber = (int)'+' + ThePhonePrefix + TheBizNumber;
```

What you meant to write was:

```
MyObject.PhoneNumber = "+" + ThePhonePrefix + TheBizNumber;
```

...although it may be more clear if you wrote it using a format string (also it's easier to extend later without making arithmetic errors:

```
MyObject.PhoneNumber = string.Format("+{0}{1}", ThePhonePrefix, TheBizNumber);
```

---

I like to note in these situations that the core issue is that the `+` operator is overloaded. It performs both addition as well as string concatenation. Some languages avoid this issue by using a separate operator. PHP is a great example for this case (a rare occurrence for sure) in that it uses `+` for addition, and `.` for concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of overloads of the `+` operator (see the specs for a list of all of them).  There are two of them that are relevant to the example at hand:

```
operator +(string, object)
operator +(int, int)
```

Since `ThePhonePrefix` is an int, it is implicitly convertible to either of these overloads.  It, like all objects, is implicitly convertible to `object` (through a boxing operation in this case) and it is exactly an `int`, so it matches that overload without needing any conversion.

`'+'` is a char, which has an implicit conversion to `int` (it will use the numeric value of the character as is defined in the UTF-16 specs, in this case, it's 43).  It's *not* implicitly convertible to `string`.  So the `(int, int)` overload matches and performs integer addition.

Were you to use `"+"` instead of `'+'` (a string instead of a char) then that value would *not* be implicitly convertible to `int` (string has no implicit conversion to `int`) and it *would* be convertible to `string` (since it is a string).  That would match the first overload I mentioned, and perform string concatenation on the two objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's a character, not a string.
String operator + does concatenation. char operator + does addition.

Comment: well, strictly speaking, there *is* no `+` operator that accepts a char.